# Initialising 2 dimensional arrays in c having large array lengths like 10000 giving error in compile time

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was trying to initialise a 2-d array with both the inner and outer array size ranging from 1-100000. So i tried by declaring it as follows:

[image]

But its showing the error:

[image]

If the same thing is done for array of smaller size say 20 its working. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Please don't just link images of text; copy and paste the relevant code and error messaging into the body of your question.

Comment: You array is too long for the stack (and also for the heap), make it shorter and then use static, global or `malloc`.

Comment: Anyway, the underlying problem is you're a) trying to allocate a gigantic array on the stack, and b) you're trying to allocate a _gigantic_ array. A 100000x100000 array of 4-byte ints is nearly 40 gigabytes in size, if my maths hasn't failed me.

Comment: Why do you use the C++ tag?

Comment: Please post the text as text, not as images. That being said, you are blowing up the stack.

Comment: @manni66 because they are using iostreams ;-) maybe we need a "C+" tag for people who write C with a tiny sprinkling of the worst features of C++...

Answer (score 2):

You put to much on the stack.. Instead malloc your dynamic/static 2D-array like this ->

```
int (*array) [Y] = malloc(sizeof(int[X][Y]));
```

Access your array like this ->

```
int g=array[0][0];
```

And set like this ->

```
array[0][0]=0;
```

(Remember to free when done)

/A

Comment: Have you perhaps heard about [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and [`delete`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete)?

Comment: Thats to new school for me. :)

Comment: Furthermore, a malloced array is never static.

Comment: Whilst your answer is largely correct, it probably won't help the fact that the OP is trying to allocate a 10-billion element array, and populate it from a source file which could contain nearly 100GB of text-form numbers. I think they have deeper problems than how to allocate arrays ;-)

Comment: I do agree to that 100%. However the OP might be working in the Sunway TaihuLight group and need some help allocating memory..;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use dynamic allocation too allocate a massive account of memory. Remember also to compile in 64 bit, because you're breaking the 4Gb limit of 32 bit. Anyway, here how you should do it:

```
std::vector a(10000 * 10000);
```

The rest of the code stays pretty much the same. You'd just need to change `a[i][j]` to `a[i*10000+j]`

If you really don't want to use vector, try at least  unique pointers:

```
auto a = std::make_unique<int[]>(10000 * 10000);
```

Again, the rest of code should use the 1d accessor.